# Python urllib2.urlopen returning 302 error even though page exists

Tags: python

I am using the Python function `urllib2.urlopen` to read the http://www.bad.org.uk/ website but I keep getting a 302 error even though when I visit the site it loads ok.  Anyone have any idea why?

```
import socket 

headers = { 'User-Agent' : 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.5; Windows NT)' }

socket.setdefaulttimeout(10)

try:
    req = urllib2.Request('http://www.bad.org.uk/', None, headers)
    urllib2.urlopen(req)
    return True         # URL Exist
except ValueError, ex:
    print 'URL: %s not well formatted' % 'http://www.bad.org.uk/'
    return False        # URL not well formatted
except urllib2.HTTPError, ex:
    print 'The server couldn\'t fulfill the request for %s.' % 'http://www.bad.org.uk/'
    print 'Error code: ', ex.code
    return False
except urllib2.URLError, ex:
    print 'We failed to reach a server for %s.' % 'http://www.bad.org.uk/'
    print 'Reason: ', ex.reason
    return False        # URL don't seem to be alive
```

Error printed:

```
The server couldn't fulfill the request for http://www.bad.org.uk//site/1/default.aspx.
Error code:  302
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The page at http://www.bad.org.uk/ is broken when cookies are disabled.

http://www.bad.org.uk/ returns:

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Location: http://www.bad.org.uk/DesktopDefault.aspx
Set-Cookie: Esperantus_Language_bad=en-GB; path=/
Set-Cookie: Esperantus_Language_rainbow=en-GB; path=/
Set-Cookie: PortalAlias=rainbow; path=/
Set-Cookie: refreshed=true; expires=Thu, 04-Nov-2010 16:21:23 GMT; path=/
Set-Cookie: .ASPXAUTH=; expires=Mon, 11-Oct-1999 23:00:00 GMT; path=/; HttpOnly
Set-Cookie: portalroles=; expires=Mon, 11-Oct-1999 23:00:00 GMT; path=/
```

If I then request http://www.bad.org.uk/DesktopDefault.aspx *without* setting these cookies, it gives another 302 and a redirect to itself.

`urllib2` is ignoring the cookies and sending the new request without cookies, so it causes a redirect loop at that URL.  To handle this, you need to add a cookie handler:

```
import urllib2
opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor())
response = opener.open('http://www.bad.org.uk')
print response.read()
```

Answer (score 3):

Code 302 is a temporary redirect, so you should get the URI from the Location field of the response and request that.

Comment: how do I do that?  Sorry I'm quite new to Python and have not used the urllib2 before

Comment: @John - That's a different question!

Comment: 302s are automatically handled by urllib2 by default.

Comment: @GlennMaynard I don't think so. Because even I am getting the same error.
Error->
`urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 302: The HTTP server returned a redirect error that would lead to an infinite loop.
The last 30x error message was:
Found`
Any suggestion ?

Comment: @YogeeshSeralathan The error message you pasted isn't the same as anything on this page, but it seems pretty self-explanatory: the page has a redirect loop.  You should open a new question.

Comment: @GlennMaynard Got the issue fixed by using different module 'requests'. 'urllib2' is good but still needs a lot of improvement I guess.