# Handling rss redirects with Python/urllib2

Tags: python, redirect, urllib2

Calling `urrlib2.urlopen` on a link to an article fetched from an RSS feed leads to the following error:

> urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 301: The HTTP server returned a redirect
>   error tha t would lead to an infinite loop. The last 30x error message
>   was: Moved Permanently

According to the documentation, urllib2 supports redirects.

On Java the problem was solved by just calling

`HttpURLConnection.setFollowRedirects(true);`

How can I solve it with Python?

**UPDATE**

The link I'm having problems with:

http://feeds.nytimes.com/click.phdo?i=8cd5af579b320b0bfd695ddcc344d96c

Comment: Redirects are on by default. Read the error message again. To determine if this is an error in the std-lib you would have to supply the URL, for checking. Note, that also the server could return different stuff based on the sent User-Agent.

Comment: I've added the url. Looks like there are more than 5 redirects. But Java copes with them without any extra stuff like user agent.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python urllib2.urlopen returning 302 error even though page exists](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4098702/python-urllib2-urlopen-returning-302-error-even-though-page-exists)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Turns out you need to enable Cookies. The page redirects to itself after setting a cookie first. Because urllib2 does not handle cookies by default you have to do it yourself.

```
import urllib2
import urllib
from cookielib import CookieJar

cj = CookieJar()
opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cj))
p = opener.open("http://feeds.nytimes.com/click.phdo?i=8cd5af579b320b0bfd695ddcc344d96c")

print p.read()
```

Answer (score 9):

Nothing wrong with @sleeplessnerd's solution, but this is very, very slightly more elegant:

```
import urllib2
url = "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9926023/handling-rss-redirects-with-python-urllib2"
p = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor).open(url)

print p.read()
```

In fact, if you look at the inline documentation for the `CookieJar()` function, it more-or-less tells you to do things this way:

`You may not need to know about this class: try urllib2.build_opener(HTTPCookieProcessor).open(url)`

Comment: If implemented this way is the cookiejar shared between subsequent requests? (Does HTTPCookieProcessor use a singleton-cache for the cookies, or a new cookie jar each time?)