# Python, IOError: cannot identify image file

Tags: python, python-2.7, image-processing, python-imaging-library

I know that there is a lot of questions similar questions, but I think, that there is not an igual (I think). I have an array of image's urls and I want to download it. But when I try to save images I get this error. I don't know how to make it works.

This is my code:

```
listOfImagesUrl = ['https://cdn.psychologytoday.com/sites/default/files/blogs/1023/2012/09/105928-103553.jpg', 'http://i.livescience.com/images/i/000/048/264/original/disgusted-101130-02.jpg%3F1324346664', 'http://barfblog.com/wp-content/uploads/images/disgust.story.jpg', 'http://cache1.asset-cache.net/gc/148190074-people-making-disgusted-faces-gettyimages.jpg%3Fv%3D1%26c%3DIWSAsset%26k%3D2%26d%3Dww%252BvNwEe%252BXzLnQze1Z2w9KNDivKR%252BEqGJ2cPfDe1oeinIezLX%252B8y1tIG3LNjTbL5']

imageNumber = 1

for imageUrl in listOfImagesUrl:

    file = cStringIO.StringIO(urllib.urlopen(imageUrl).read())
    img = Image.open(file)
    img.save("/tmp/test/" + str(imageNumber) + "." + img.format)
    print "DONE: " + str(imageNumber) + " of " + str(len(listOfImagesUrl))
    imageNumber += 1
```

I solved the url problem using the sleeplessnerd's answer on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9926023/handling-rss-redirects-with-python-urllib2) stackoverflow's question. The problem was that I had to enable cookies on urllib2.

Comment: The second URL gives you a 500 error when loaded with `urllib` and the response body is empty. Do check your responses before trying to read data.

Comment: The `%3F` sequence is an encoded question mark. It should not be part of the URL path, you have a query parameter (cache buster probably), encoded into the URL instead. The last URL has the same.

Comment: But, if I econde my second url to http://www.livescience.com/images/i/000/048/264/original/disgusted-101130-02.jpg it still not working. What is happening? Thanks for your help.

Comment: The end of the [`urllib.urlopen` documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html#urllib.urlopen) says "Deprecated since version 2.6: The `urlopen()` function has been removed in Python 3 in favor of [`urllib2.urlopen()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html#urllib2.urlopen)."

Comment: Thank you, I changed to urllib2 and I get a new error. urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 301: The HTTP server returned a redirect error that would lead to an infinite loop.
The last 30x error message was:
Moved Permanently.

I'll search a fix for this error now.

Comment: You might want to try using a different url for testing. i.e. put the barfblog.com first in the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I switch to `urllib2` and restructured your code as shown to provide more error information. Seems that most of your image URLs are no good.

```
from urllib2 import urlopen, URLError
from cStringIO import StringIO
from PIL import Image

listOfImagesUrl = [
    'http://barfblog.com/wp-content/uploads/images/disgust.story.jpg',
    'https://cdn.psychologytoday.com/sites/default/files/blogs/1023/2012/09/105928-103553.jpg',
    'http://i.livescience.com/images/i/000/048/264/original/disgusted-101130-02.jpg%3F1324346664',
    'http://cache1.asset-cache.net/gc/148190074-people-making-disgusted-faces-gettyimages.jpg%3Fv%3D1%26c%3DIWSAsset%26k%3D2%26d%3Dww%252BvNwEe%252BXzLnQze1Z2w9KNDivKR%252BEqGJ2cPfDe1oeinIezLX%252B8y1tIG3LNjTbL5'
]

for imageNumber, imageUrl in enumerate(listOfImagesUrl, start=1):
    try:
        url = urlopen(imageUrl)
    except URLError as e:
        print "skipping {}".format(imageUrl)
        print "  error: {}".format(e)
        continue
    file = StringIO(url.read())
    img = Image.open(file)
    img.save("/tmp/test/" + str(imageNumber) + "." + img.format)
    print "DONE: " + str(imageNumber) + " of " + str(len(listOfImagesUrl))
```

Comment: Thank you martineau, your code is much better than mine. One thing that I did not understand is why I get those errors? If I open the urls on a browser, it shows me an image. What is happening?

Comment: @Caaarlos: Thanks for accepting my answer even though I didn't know about needing to enable cookies for the urls to work.