# urlopen Returning Redirect Error for Valid Links

Tags: python-3.x, httprequest, urllib

I'm building a broken link checker in python, and it's becoming a chore building the logic for correctly identifying links that do not resolve when visited with a browser. I've found a set of links where I can consistently reproduce a redirect error with my scraper, but which resolve perfectly when visited in a browser. I was hoping I could find some insight here.

```
import urllib
import urllib.request
import html.parser
import requests
from requests.exceptions import HTTPError
from socket import error as SocketError

try:
    req=urllib.request.Request(url, None, {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686; G518Rco3Yp0uLV40Lcc9hAzC1BOROTJADjicLjOmlr4=) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.157 Safari/537.36','Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8','Accept-Charset': 'ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3','Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, sdch','Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.8','Connection': 'keep-alive'})
    response = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
    raw_response = response.read().decode('utf8', errors='ignore')
    response.close()
except urllib.request.HTTPError as inst:
    output = format(inst)


print(output)
```

In this instance, an example of a URL that reliably returns this error is 'http://forums.hostgator.com/want-see-your-sites-dns-propagating-t48838.html'. It resolves perfectly when visited but the code above will return the following error:

```
HTTP Error 301: The HTTP server returned a redirect error that would lead to an infinite loop.
The last 30x error message was:
Moved Permanently
```

Any ideas how I can correctly identify these links as functional without blindly ignoring links from that site (which might miss genuinely broken links)?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You get the infinite loop error because the page you want to scrape uses cookies and redirects when the cookie isn't sent by the client. You'll get the same error with most other scraper tools and also with browsers when you disallow cookies.

You need a `http.cookiejar.CookieJar` and a `urllib.request.HTTPCookieProcessor` to avoid the redirect loop:

```
import urllib
import urllib.request
import html.parser
import requests
from requests.exceptions import HTTPError
from socket import error as SocketError
from http.cookiejar import CookieJar

try:
    req=urllib.request.Request(url, None, {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686; G518Rco3Yp0uLV40Lcc9hAzC1BOROTJADjicLjOmlr4=) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.157 Safari/537.36','Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8','Accept-Charset': 'ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3','Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, sdch','Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.8','Connection': 'keep-alive'})
    cj = CookieJar()
    opener = urllib.request.build_opener(urllib.request.HTTPCookieProcessor(cj))
    response = opener.open(req)
    raw_response = response.read().decode('utf8', errors='ignore')
    response.close()
except urllib.request.HTTPError as inst:
    output = format(inst)
    print(output)
```

Comment: For some reason [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4098702/python-urllib2-urlopen-returning-302-error-even-though-page-exists) works for me on `python2`, but not your answer. I continue get a 302 infinite loop error with this method. Any suggestions?

Comment: Some modules were renamed when Python switched from version 2 to 3. You need to replace `urllib` with `urllib2`, `http.cookiejar` with `cookielib` etc. I tested it a few minutes ago with the url mentioned in the question above and it worked with Python 2.7

Comment: Might not have been clear, but I meant I *could* open the URL with the `python2` method linked, but *not* with yours. That said, I think we can ignore and that the website I was trying might have blocked me due to too many pulls in too little time (couldn't even visit it in a browser). It's back today and working. I think I was confused re. what wasn't working. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I concur with the comments in the 1st answer and it wasn't working for me (I was getting some encoded/compressed byte data, nothing readable)

The link mentioned used urllib2. It also works with urllib in python 3.7 as follow:

```
from urllib.request import build_opener, HTTPCookieProcessor
opener = build_opener(HTTPCookieProcessor())
response = opener.open('http://www.bad.org.uk')
print response.read()
```

Comment: For Python 3 and were I to do this today, I would likely use the tools in the requests library: https://2.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#cookies

Answer (score 1):

I tried the solutions above without success.

It appears that this problem can occur when the URL you are trying to open is badly formed (or just not what the REST service is expecting).  For example, I found my problem was because I requested `https://host.com/users/4484486` where the host was expecting a slash at the end: `https://host.com/users/4484486/` solved the problem.

Comment: If I were to try this again today I would use the requests library and the cookie functions appropriate to that tool:

https://2.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#cookies

Comment: I also encountered this issue when I accidentally used an `&`  instead of `?` when typing a URL from memory (Ex: `https://xxx.yyy/zzz&page=3` -> `https://xxx.yyy/zzz?page=3`)