# urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 302

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup, urllib, html-parser

I am trying to Parse a website using Python3.6 using the HTML parser, but it throws ab error as follows:

> **urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 302: The HTTP server returned a redirect error that would lead to an infinite loop.
>   The last 30x error message was:
>   Found**
>   The code I wrote is as below:
>   {

```
from urllib.request import urlopen as uo
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import ssl

# Ignore SSL Certification
ctx = ssl.create_default_context()
ctx.check_hostname = False
ctx.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_NONE

url = input('Enter--')
html = uo(url,context = ctx).read()

soup = BeautifulSoup(html,"html.parser")

print(soup)
#retrieve all the anchor tags
#tags = soup('a')
```

}

Can someone tell me why is it throwing this error , what it means and how to solve this error?

Comment: sounds like a server error. Can you give us the url you are connecting to?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [urlopen Returning Redirect Error for Valid Links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32569934/urlopen-returning-redirect-error-for-valid-links)

Comment: url is :http://apnakhata.raj.nic.in

Comment: That site sets a cookie and then redirects to /Home.aspx.  You need a cookie container.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in the comments:

> That site sets a cookie and then redirects to /Home.aspx.

To avoid the loop of redirects on this site, you must have 24 chars `ASP.NET_SessionId` cookie set.

```
import urllib.request
opener = urllib.request.build_opener()
opener.addheaders.append(('Cookie', 'ASP.NET_SessionId=garbagegarbagegarbagelol'))
f = opener.open("http://apnakhata.raj.nic.in/")
html = f.read()
```

However, I'd just use [`requests`](http://html.python-requests.org/).

```
import requests

r = requests.get('http://apnakhata.raj.nic.in/')
html = r.text
```

It saves cookies to a RequestsCookieJar by default. After the initial request, only one redirect happens. You can see it here:

```
>>> r.history[0]
[<Response [302]>]

>>> r.history[0].cookies
<RequestsCookieJar[Cookie(version=0, name='ASP.NET_SessionId', value='ph0chopmjlpi1dg0f3xtbacu', port=None, port_specified=False, domain='apnakhata.raj.nic.in', domain_specified=False, domain_initial_dot=False, path='/', path_specified=True, secure=False, expires=None, discard=True, comment=None, comment_url=None, rest={'HttpOnly': None}, rfc2109=False)]>
```

To scrape the page, you can use [`requests_html`](http://html.python-requests.org/) created by the same author.

```
from requests_html import HTMLSession
session = HTMLSession()
r = session.get('http://apnakhata.raj.nic.in/')
```

Getting links is extremely easy:

```
>>> r.html.absolute_links
{'http://apnakhata.raj.nic.in/',
'http://apnakhata.raj.nic.in/Cyberlist.aspx',
...
'http://apnakhata.raj.nic.in/rev_phone.aspx'}
```

Answer (score 0):

The HyperText Transfer Protocol (HTTP) 302 Found redirect status response code indicates that the resource requested has been temporarily moved to the URL given by the Location header. A browser redirects to this page but search engines don't update their links to the resource (in 'SEO-speak', it is said that the 'link-juice' is not sent to the new URL).

Even if the specification requires the method (and the body) not to be altered when the redirection is performed, not all user-agents conform here - you can still find this type of bugged software out there. It is therefore recommended to set the 302 code only as a response for GET or HEAD methods and to use [307 Temporary Redirect instead](https://www.lookhindi.com/apna-khata-rajasthan/), as the method change is explicitly prohibited in that case.

In the cases where you want the method used to be changed to GET, use 303 See Other instead. This is useful when you want to give a response to a PUT method that is not the uploaded resource but a confirmation message such as: 'you successfully uploaded XYZ'.